# C# - FileHelpers: Bad computing of DateTime variable

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv, filehelpers, csv-import

I have this sample **CSV** file:

```
Filip    Malýn        Male  1218-02-1994
Božena   Němcová      Female1804-02-1820
Jan      Žižka        Male  0719-09-1360
Che      Guevara      Male  2714-06-1928
AntoinedeSaint-ExupéryMale  1529-06-1900
```

I load it in a code by this function:

```
FileHelperEngine<T>().ReadFile(fileName);
```

But it ends up with this error:

```
FileHelpers.BadUsageException: 'The string '18-02-1994' (length 10) at line 1 has less chars than the defined for BirthDate (11). You can use the [FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)] to avoid this problem.'
```

And if I add `[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]` to the code it ends up with this error:

```
FileHelpers.ConvertException: 'Error Converting 'al' to type: 'Int32'. '
```

This is a class I use:

```
using System;
using FileHelpers;

namespace ImportExport.Mapping.FixedLength
{
    [FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
    public class Person
    {
        [FieldFixedLength(9)]
        public String Name;

        [FieldFixedLength(13)]
        public String Surname;

        [FieldFixedLength(6)]
        public String Gender;

        [FieldFixedLength(2)]
        public Int32 OrderNum;

        [FieldFixedLength(11)]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
        public DateTime BirthDate;
    }
}
```

I have been couting it so many times and tried a lot of version but with no success. What's wrong?

Comment: `[FieldFixedLength(11)]` should be `[FieldFixedLength(10)]`. 01-01-2000 is 10 characters, not 11.

Comment: "dd-MM-yyyy".Length == 10  - Note that the error message states that.

Comment: Oh! You have a point. But there is still `FileHelpers.ConvertException: 'Error Converting 'al' to type: 'Int32'. ' error.` error.

Comment: I'd be wondering about the encoding of this file, including the use of combining characters, any specified or assumed encoding that `FileHelpers` is working with and whether what it's actually working is characters or code points.

Comment: You did something wrong, and it gave an error. You changed it to something else (hint - `AllowLessChars`), and you got a different error. You fixed the first bug - but did you remember to reverse the **second** thing you tried?

Comment: The problem that the records contains diacritic so the real size is different.

Comment: Note that the error message does give the correct string (_'18-02-1994'_ ) despite the character _"ý"_, so it appears to be getting the string lengths correct, otherwise the date would be offset.

Comment: Thanks all. The solution is adding an info about encoding of the file. In my case changing `FileHelperEngine<T>().ReadFile(fileName);` to `FileHelperEngine<T>(Encoding.UTF8).ReadFile(fileName);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. The solution is adding an info about encoding of the file. In my case changing `FileHelperEngine<T>().ReadFile(fileName);` to `FileHelperEngine<T>(Encoding.UTF8).ReadFile(fileName);`.

Comment: Still doesn't match with the code though as you're saying that birth date is 11 characters but in reality it's just 10. Good that you solved your problem but this can't be the whole solution.

Comment: Yes, I have admitted this in a comment section below my question. In my opinion I wouldn't edit the code in question due to loss of continuity.